# How to Hide class Using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Enfold theme for my client's project. I want to `display:none` a class when i scroll down.

Here's my code:

```
if(!header.length) return;

        var logo            = $('#header_main .container .logo img, #header_main .container .logo a'),
            elements        = $('#header_main .container, #header_main .main_menu ul:first-child > li > a:not(.avia_mega_div a)'),
            el_height       = $(elements).filter(':first').height(),
            isMobile        = $.avia_utilities.isMobile,
            scroll_top      = $('#scroll-top-link'),
            transparent     = header.is('.av_header_transparency'),
            shrinking       = header.is('.av_header_shrinking'),
            set_height      = function()
            {   
                var st = win.scrollTop(), newH = 0;

                if(shrinking && !isMobile)
                {
                    if(st < el_height/0)
                    {
                        newH = el_height - st;
                        header.removeClass('header-scrolled');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newH = el_height/0;
                        header.addClass('header-scrolled');

                    }

                    elements.css({'height': newH + 'px', 'lineHeight': newH + 'px' });
                    logo.css({'maxHeight': newH + 'px'});
                }
```

Now, When i scroll down this code returns the class with `height:0px`, i want to change it and return as `display:none`

Thanks,

Comment: `el_height/0` ? Good luck.

Comment: simply use `element.css('display','none');`

Comment: Where is the code that detects the scrolling?

Comment: @hsz yaa, I'm not good at this..

Comment: @user3378765 While [division by zero](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-infinity-property) does not cause an error in Javascript, this evaluates to Infinity

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys, i defined a new variable with value none and put that in the else condition. magic happened.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to show/hide class using jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#myselector').change(function() {
    $('.classname').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).val()).show();    
 });
 });
```